# media-queries and responsive design how does it works

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Can anybody tell me why exactly this works

```
/* small desktop */
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {

}

/* tablet */
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {

}

/* mobile phone */
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {

}
```

but this not:

```
/* mobile phone */
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {

}

/* tablet */
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {

}

/* small desktop */
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {

}
```

since the last style always overwrite the previous style like :

```
[class=foo]{
    background:red;
    background:yellow;
  }
```

output:

```
.foo background yellow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply: stylesheets cascade, so if the condition is true, it will override any previous. Your second example is a mobile-first approach, so you would need to use min-width.

```
/* mobile phone */
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {

}

/* tablet */
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {

}

/* small desktop */
@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {

}
```